# How do i find all files in a folder recursively by the specific name and rename them?

Tags: debian

I have a tree of folders. Some of them contain file named ".file.php"
How do i rename all the files with this name recursively in the tree to ".file1.php"?
I'm on debian server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full solution would look as follows

```
find -name '*.file.php' -exec rename 's/\.file\.php$/.file1.php/' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have `rename` on debian? idk, but since it's available on ubuntu, I guess so.

> NAME
>          rename - renames multiple files
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          "rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule
>   specified
>          as the first argument.  The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression
>          which is expected to modify the $_ string in Perl for at least some of
>          the filenames specified.  If a given filename is not modified by the
>          expression, it will not be renamed.  If no filenames are given on
>   the
>          command line, filenames will be read via standard input.
>
> ```
>    For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the
>    extension, you might say
>
>            rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
>
>    To translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use
>
>            rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
> ```

an example copied from a google result might be already quite near to what you want:

> Here is an example of the rename command:
>
> rename -n ’s/.htm$/.html/’ *.htm
>
> The -n means that it's a test run and
>   will not actually change any files. It
>   will show you a list of files that
>   would be renamed if you removed the
>   -n. In the case above, it will convert all files in the current directory
>   from a file extension of .htm to
>   .html.
>
> If the output of the above test run
>   looked ok then you could run the final
>   version:
>
> rename -v ’s/.htm$/.html/’ *.htm
>
> The -v is optional, but it's a good
>   idea to include it because it is the
>   only record you will have of changes
>   that were made by the rename
>   command....

Comment: how do i do it recursively in a tree of folders?

Comment: Ubuntu is debian

Comment: @die_humans: Look here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=6642616 for one way to do it. another way would be a shell script.