# Recursively rename files - oneliner preferably

Tags: bash

I found this answer [how do i...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33626/how-do-i-find-all-files-in-a-folder-recursively-by-the-specific-name-and-rename) but it simply doesn't work - it did not rename any file for unknown to me reason

Before I started to search around I thought that it should be easy task even for novice penguin, but it doesn't seem so for me.

For example, I simply can't tell `ls` to list all `*.txt` in all subfolders, which was surprise to me (without grep or similar).
Then I found `find` and `find . -name name_1.txt` lists files fine, but

`for f in $(find . -name name_1.txt) ; do echo "$f" ; done`

splits whole file paths with space as separator, so it's unusable to pass that output to some command like `mv` or `rename`

I want to ask whats wrong with above command and if possible some nifty oneliner so I can recursively rename `name_1.txt` to `name_2.txt`

Comment: What's the error you got when executing the command found in the other answer? Does any of your filenames contain a space in it?

Comment: I don't get error, but none file was renamed. Filename does not have spaces but subfolder names do. It's on Windows NTFS partition but that shouldn't change things I guess

Comment: I believe that's the reason it didn't work for you. The answer from @ams with `find -print0` and `xargs -0` uses the null character as a separator to avoid whitespace problems in the file names.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/oldname/newname}"'`

Obviously, that rename pattern is just a simple example, but beware that as is it will edit the whole path, not just the filename.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. As I don't get xargs logic (and your warning), could you just edit `"${0/oldname/newname}"` part with case where I want to rename all files named `name_1.txt` to `name_2.txt` recursively. Should it be `"${0/name_1.txt/name_2.txt}"`?

Comment: I tried is on sample folder and it works as assumed in my previous comment

Comment: Let me break it down: `print0` makes find output zero-terminated strings, so spaces are safe; `-0` makes xargs expect zero-terminated input; `-n1` says to invoke bash once for each file; and `${0/old/new}` is bash syntax for find and replace in variable `$0`. Hope that helps.

Comment: It's sure interesting :) and new to me, and usable in future terminal sessions

Answer (score 4):

the [mmv command](http://man-wiki.net/index.php/1%3ammv) will do this in a rather simple call:

mmv ";name_1.txt" "#1name_2.txt"

The ";" wildcard, which is reused in the replacement filename as "#1" matches also subdirectories.

If you need more complicated examples, you should look into the man-page.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't tried it as it's currently not installed on my 11.04 and first answer worked fine. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

As @ams points out, many recursive replace solutions require you to work with the whole path, not just the file name.

I use `find`'s `-execdir` action to solve this problem. If you use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`, the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file. So, instead of passing the whole path to `rename`, it only passes `./filename`. That makes it much easier to write the replace command.

```
find /the/path -type f \
               -name '*_one.txt' \
               -execdir rename 's/\.\/(.+)_one\.txt$/$1_two.txt/' {} \;
```

In detail:

- `-type f` means only look for files, not directories
- `-name '*_one.txt'` means means only match filenames that end in _one.txt
- In this answer, I'm using the `rename` command instead of mv. rename uses a Perl regular expression to rename each file.
- The backslashes after `-type` and `-name` are the bash line-continuation character. I use them to make this example more readable, but they are not needed in practice.
- However, the backslash at the end of the `-execdir` line is required. It is there to esacpe the semicolon, which terminates the command run by `-execdir`. Fun!

Explanation of the regex:

- `s/` start of the regex
- `\.\/` match the leading ./ that -execdir passes in. Use \ to escape the . and / metacharacters
- `(.+)` match the start of the filename. The parentheses capture the match for later use
- `_one\.txt` match "_one.txt", escape the dot metacharacter
- `$` anchor the match at the end of the string
- `/` marks the end of the "match" part of the regex, and the start of the "replace" part
- `$1` references the existing filename, because we captured it with parentheses. If you use multiple sets of parentheses in the "match" part, you can refer to them here using $2, $3, etc.
- `_two.txt` the new file name will end in "_two.txt". No need to escape the dot metacharacter here in the "replace" section
- `/` end of the regex

Before

```
tree --charset=ascii

|-- a_one.txt
|-- b_one.txt
|-- Not_this.txt
`-- dir1
    `-- c_one.txt
```

After

```
tree --charset=ascii

|-- a_two.txt
|-- b_two.txt
|-- Not_this.txt
`-- dir1
    `-- c_two.txt
```

---

Hint: `rename`'s -n option is useful. It does a dry run and shows you what names it will change, but does not make any changes.

Comment: `execdir` is good, by why not just `find ~/the/path -type f -name '*_one.txt' -execdir bash -c 'mv -- "$0" "${0%one.txt}two.txt"' {} \;`? It is easier to read and memorize.

Answer (score 0):

You could explore the plethora of choices available:

```
`$ apt-cache search rename | grep -i rename`
```