# renaming a large tree of "folder_names" to "folder names"

Tags: files, rename

A friend of mine took the liberty to remove all white-spaces " " in the foldernames on our shared drives and substitute them with the underline character "_" . The filenames are unaffected, and the error is systematic propagated in foldernames only

Any good proposal on which command could resolve this?

Thanks..!

Comment: Why do you want to put the white spaces back in? Names without white space are much easier to work with in the terminal as well as other things

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/33626/how-do-i-find-all-files-in-a-folder-recursively-by-the-specific-name-and-rename

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911301/rename-multiple-files-shell/6911389#6911389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to go back to spaces, here is the command, only for files

```
find /path -type f -iname '*_*' -exec bash -c 'echo mv -i "$1" "${1//_/ }"' _ {} \;
```

This only shows what would do, remove the `echo` to really exec.

Next you can change also directory substituting `-type f` with `-type d`.

Comment: This worked perfectly: 
find -type d -iname '*_*' -exec bash -c 'mv -i "$1" "${1//_/ }"' _ {} \;

Thank you enzotib!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `rename` tool:

```
$ rename "_" " " */*/ */*/*/
```

Comment: /media/gb_01/ folders already exist$ rename "_" " " */*/ */*/*/
Bareword "_" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1.

Comment: be sure to get your quotes right.